# issue on printing woocommerce notices after user registration redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm playing with this filter (`woocommerce_registration_redirect`) to log out user just after registeration and show a temporary message.

Here's what I've done

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect',  'redirect_after_register'  );


function redirect_after_register() {
        wp_logout();
        wc_add_notice( __( 'SOME MESSAGE', 'woocommerce' ), "notice" );
        return wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' );
    }
```

After user registration, I redirect him to my account page, where `wc_print_notices()` must display my custom notice message.
Unfortunately, it doesn't' work and the message doesn't appear.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: it will not work because [`wc_add_notice`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/5893875b0c03dda7b2d448d1a904ccfad3cdae3f/includes/wc-notice-functions.php#L75) is using the session... [`wp_logout()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout) destroys the current session *(and nothing initializes a new session I guess...)*

Comment: It's not because of wp_logout(), I tried commenting it but no effect

Answer (score 2):

This is because the customer/user does not yet have an active cookie session. This is done usually when adding an item to the cart.

```
// Only create when there is none, e.g may clear the existing cart item
if ( ! WC()->session->has_session() ) {
  WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);

}

// Then you add your notice here.
wc_add_notice( __('Message', 'domain'), 'success' );
```

Take a look at the comment: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-session-handler.php#L76

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the message to appear AFTER the re-direct, correct? This code seems to add the notice to the page BEFORE the redirect. You would have to devise some mechanism fire your function after the re-direct actually happens. This is the same problem faced with you try to do something with upon a plugin activation. You can use the same solution in the codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook

Comment: No, I'm just adding the message to the WC session for future printing in the account page. It should work like sessions but something is wrong.

Comment: But you're logging out first, then adding a message, then redirecting. So are you trying to print a static message for all non logged in users? Can you even do that? It wouldn't STAY in the message buffer. I would think that messages would be based on the current logged in user. So what happens when you try to send a message to a logged out user? Well I think we figured out... nothing! In other words, the system connects the message with the logged in user who is supposed to receive it. Your user is logged out.

Comment: I also tested without having logout function, and it doesn't work again.